# Google Calendar App Script to pull Data into a Spreadsheet periodically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

I've been using this script to pull Data from Google Calendar into a spreadsheet. I have a couple questions for improvements:

1. Is it possible to have this pull data from multiple calendars to the same spreadsheet without them overwriting each other?
2. Is it possible to have it add a new column of data to the spreadsheet that marks which calendar each row came from?
3. Also, how would you go about setting this up to run automatically every 24 hours?

THANKS!

```
function caltest3(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET ID");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CALENDAR ID");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, 2013"), new Date("January 13, 2013"));
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
  //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendarevent.html
      var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getStartTime(),            
                    events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getDescription(),
                    events[i].getLocation()]];
  var row=i+1;
  var range=sheet.getRange(row+1,1,1,5);
  range.setValues(details);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All your question have a YES ... but need some enlightenment:if run every 24 hours I presume looking for events in a specific time period?  What period? 24 hours?  How many calendars?  Why not one sheet for each calendar?Do you want the events to be classified by cal names or by time?

Comment: It would be the same period each time, 1/4 year, and there will be functions in the spreadsheets to sort the past items from the future. It will likely be 4 calendars, and they need to be aggregated, then the data will be sorted in the spreadsheets. I'm not sure what classified by refers to here? Both calendar names and time should be details that get passed through. I would prefer they be sorted by time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answers then an example:

1. You cannot do this with a single call to the `CalendarApp`, but if you loop through a list of calendarIds and add the resultant events for that calendar to an array, you can then sort this array and put this to the spreadsheet
2. Simply add the calendar name (or id) as another item in your `details` array, just remember to increase your range column count by `1`
3. Add a script trigger to whatever period you want, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_time_triggers) describes this best.

Whether you are building an array of calendar events from multiple calendars or just one, adding them to an array in a loop and then writing them to the spreadsheet outside any loop is better practice than writing row by row as every time you call the `getRange()` & `setValues` methods they are separate API calls and these calls are most expensive in time for Apps Script. Call each only once with a range to suit your data and your script will run an order of magnitude quicker.

Script below illustrates answers 1 & 2. Your needs may vary if you are setting a timer to this as you may be wanting to affect the period of time you are querying?

```
function caltest3(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById( 'spreadsheetId' ),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName( 'sheetName' ),
      cals = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'], c, cal, calName,
      start = new Date( 'whenever' ), end = new Date( 'whenever' ),
      events, i, details,
      eventslog = [], e,
      rows = [], range;

  for (c = 0; c < cals.length; c += 1) {

    cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(cals[c]);
    calName = cal.getTitle();
    events = cal.getEvents(start, end);

    // add the events of the current calendar to the array of all events
    eventslog = eventslog.concat(
      events.map(function(event) {
        return {
          time: new Date(event.getStartTime()).getTime(), // sort by this
          details: [
            event.getTitle(),
            event.getStartTime(),
            event.getEndTime(),
            event.getDescription(),
            event.getLocation(),
            calName // change calendar info position in array to suit
          ]
        };
      })
    );
  }

  // sort array of event so date order can be either way by reversing a & b
  eventslog.sort(function(a, b) { return a.time - b.time; });

  rows = eventslog.map(function(entry) { return entry.details; });

  range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 6);
  range.setValues(rows);
}
```

> code spaced out for clarity

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on this line: rows[] = eventslog.map(function(entry) { return entry.details; });      I'm also getting a 'sheets not defined' error for this line:  for (c = 0; c < sheets.length; c += 1) (I did put the name of the sheet in where it says 'sheetName' at the top, which I thought that was referring too)

Comment: I'm still getting a syntax error with the  rows[] = eventslog.map(function(entry) { return entry.details; }); line

Comment: all fixed `rows[]` should be `rows` - last time i write code direct to stackoverflow without testing