# Adding new calendar events automatically to my google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am looking for a function, that immediately adds new calendar events to my google sheet via google script. I don't want to import the full calendar or all the events that happen during a specific time. For my application, I only need the event, that was created last.
Is there a faster way instead of just testing all events and only add the ones, that aren't in the sheet yet?
I need some way, the get the last edited event via google script.
Thanks for your help!

I looked at the app-script website, but I couldn't find a function or a trigger there.

Comment: [Try SpreadsheetApp.getEvents(start,end)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents(Date,Date))

Comment: There's an installable [calendar event trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers) that runs when a user's calendar events is updated (created, edited, or deleted). There are also [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#Google%20Calendar-events) for calendar events and the documentation explains how you can use retrieve information to use in your scenario.

Comment: Further to @Cooper 's comment. [Google Calendar App Script to pull Data into a Spreadsheet periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14420328/1330560) provides an example of the use of `getEvents(start,end)`. You could use this script in a spreadsheet with a time driven trigger, and filter events that were "new" or filter out events that were already in the events in your spreadsheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Calendar App Script to pull Data into a Spreadsheet periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415752/google-calendar-app-script-to-pull-data-into-a-spreadsheet-periodically)

Answer (score 0):

```
function tester() {//for testing without timebased trigger
  let dt = new Date();
  let evobj = { year: dt.getFullYear(), month: dt.getMonth() + 1, "day-of-month": dt.getDate() }
  addNewCalEvents(evobj);
}

function addNewCalEvents(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let evtids = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow() == 0) {
    sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, 5).setValues([["CalId", "EventId", "Title", "Start", "End"]]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
  if (sh.getLastRow() > 1) {
    evtids = sh.getRange(2, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  }
    const calids = [];//add calendar ids here for all calendars you wish
    const stdt = new Date(e.year, e.month - 1, e["day-of-month"]);
    const endt = new Date(e.year, e.month + 2, e["day-of-month"]);
    let evts = [];
    calids.forEach(id => {
      CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id).getEvents(stdt, endt).forEach(ev => {
        if (!~evtids.indexOf(ev.getId())) {
          evts.push([id, ev.getId(), ev.getTitle(), ev.getStartTime(), ev.getEndTime()]);
        }
      });
    })
    if (evts.length > 0) {
      sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, evts.length, evts[0].length).setValues(evts);
    }
}

function createTimeBaseTrigger(handler) {//timebased trigger
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == handler).filter(e => e).length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("addNewCalEvents").timeBased().everyDays(1).athour(1).create();
  }
}
```